# Do endosymbiotic organelles have Latin classification?

Tags: classification

Do endosymbiotic organelles such as chloroplasts or mitochondria have Latin classification?

Comment: You might find this article interesting [Mitochondrial Evolution](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3428767/)

Answer (score 1):

As any other organelle, endosymbiotic organelles do not have a systematic name. However, their descendant prokaryotic organisms do have a genus name.